# Complex Java 17 regex with multiple token types and segments

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to build a complex Java 17 regex and am failing somewhere.

The regex/substring I am looking to match is called a "*metric set*". A metric set consists of 6 **segments**, and each of these 6 segments can be any one of a different "*token type*".

The first token type is a "*distance token*", and consists of 1 or more numeric digits [0-9] followed by a double quote. Example of distance tokens would be: `12"`, `6"`, `73"`, etc.

The second token type is a "*numeric token*" and simply consists of numeric characters `[0-9]`. It is important to note that numeric tokens can also be signed (meaning, some can be negative numbers) and contain  minus signs ("-") before them. Examples of numeric tokens are: `9`, `18`, `293`, `-4`, `-15`, etc.

The third token token type is a "*random token*". This token may start with 1+ optional numeric characters `[0-9]`, or they may be omitted. Then the token will have an upper-case "D", followed by either a 3 or a 6. Examples of random tokens are: `D3`, `D6`, `12D3`, `4D6`, etc.

The fourth token type can be the "not-applicable" token, in which case the value must be exactly `N/A`.

The fifth token type is called the "*greater-than token*", and consists of 1+ numeric digits [0-9] followed by a plus sign ("+"). Examples of greater than tokens are: `3+`, `12+`, `1+`, `0+`, `19+`, etc.

The sixth token type is called the "*ignorables token*" and consists of the words `Melee` or `Ranged`.

Those are the token types, and again, the 6 different segments of the regex allow different segments to be different token types, as explained below.

The 1st segment can be any of the following token types: distance tokens, random tokens, ignorables tokens or not-applicable tokens.

The 2nd segment can be any token type except a distance token or an ignorables token.

The 3rd segment can be any of the following token types: greater-than token, random token or not-applicable token.

The 4th segment can be any token type except a distance token or an ignorables token.

The 5th segment can be any token type except a distance token or an ignorables token.

The 6th segment can be any token type except a distance token or an ignorables token.

Please show me the Java 17 code that instantiates a string regex meeting these criteria, then matches an input string against that regex and extracts the matching metrics set (all 6 segments) from the input string if it matches.

A few examples of matching strings that conform to all of these rules would be:

```
Flamer [IGNORES COVER, TORRENT] 12" D6 N/A 4 0 1
Grav-gun [ANTI-VEHICLE 2+] 18" 2 3+ 5 -1 2
Grav-pistol [ANTI-VEHICLE 2+, PISTOL] 18" 1 3+ 4 -1 2
Hand flamer [IGNORES COVER, PISTOL, TORRENT] 12" D6 N/A 3 0 1
```

Here is my latest code representing my best attempts thus far:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class MetricSetRegexMatcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "(\\d+\"|D[36]|Melee|Ranged|N/A)(?!.*\\d+\")(\\d+|D[36]|Melee|Ranged|N/A)(\\d+\\+|D[36]|N/A)(\\d+|D[36]|Melee|Ranged|N/A)(\\d+|D[36]|Melee|Ranged|N/A)(\\d+|D[36]|Melee|Ranged|N/A)";

        String input = "Hello there: 18\" 2 3+ 9 -4 D6";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Segment " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No match!");
        }
    }
}
```

When this runs I get the output "No match!" and I'm wondering where my regex is failing to meet my criteria. Ideally I would be able to match and extract the `18" 2 3+ 9 -4 D6` from the string, for downstream processing.

Comment: This might be the same simple mistake I've made in the past. `Matcher#matches()` tries to match your regex against the whole string, even if the regex itself isn't anchored with `^` and `$`. So your "Hello there" is making the match fail. Try with `Matcher#find()`, or widen the regex to make it accept an arbitrary prefix/suffix, with e.g. `.*<your regex>.*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MetricSetRegexMatcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = ""
                + "(\\d+\"|D[36]|Melee|Ranged|N/A) "
                + "(\\d+|D[36]|Melee|Ranged|N/A) "
                + "(\\d+\\+|D[36]|N/A) "
                + "(\\d+|D[36]|Melee|Ranged|N/A) "
                + "(-?\\d+|D[36]|Melee|Ranged|N/A) " 
                + "(\\d+|D[36]|Melee|Ranged|N/A)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        List<String> inputs = List.of(
                "Hello there: 18\" 2 3+ 9 -4 D6",
                "Flamer [IGNORES COVER, TORRENT] 12\" D6 N/A 4 0 1",
                "Grav-gun [ANTI-VEHICLE 2+] 18\" 2 3+ 5 -1 2",
                "Grav-pistol [ANTI-VEHICLE 2+, PISTOL] 18\" 1 3+ 4 -1 2",
                "Hand flamer [IGNORES COVER, PISTOL, TORRENT] 12\" D6 N/A 3 0 1");

        for (String input : inputs) {
            System.out.println("input " + input);

            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Segment " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No match!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
input Hello there: 18" 2 3+ 9 -4 D6
Segment 1: 18"
Segment 2: 2
Segment 3: 3+
Segment 4: 9
Segment 5: -4
Segment 6: D6
input Flamer [IGNORES COVER, TORRENT] 12" D6 N/A 4 0 1
Segment 1: 12"
Segment 2: D6
Segment 3: N/A
Segment 4: 4
Segment 5: 0
Segment 6: 1
input Grav-gun [ANTI-VEHICLE 2+] 18" 2 3+ 5 -1 2
Segment 1: 18"
Segment 2: 2
Segment 3: 3+
Segment 4: 5
Segment 5: -1
Segment 6: 2
input Grav-pistol [ANTI-VEHICLE 2+, PISTOL] 18" 1 3+ 4 -1 2
Segment 1: 18"
Segment 2: 1
Segment 3: 3+
Segment 4: 4
Segment 5: -1
Segment 6: 2
input Hand flamer [IGNORES COVER, PISTOL, TORRENT] 12" D6 N/A 3 0 1
Segment 1: 12"
Segment 2: D6
Segment 3: N/A
Segment 4: 3
Segment 5: 0
Segment 6: 1
```

Comment: This is **perfect** thank you! How you organize the individual tokens' requirement inside their own lines is simple, elegant and helps my brain use this moving forward with other similar regexes. Thanks again! In the grim darkness of the far future, there are only regexes!